# Returning new hash key from a module

Tags: perl, hash, module

I declared a hash in my main script, and I'm trying to add a new key called "number" and give it a value.  I'm adding this new key in a subroutine defined in a separate module file.  The problem I'm having is that the new key and value is not seen when I use it in my main program.

I'm expecting the output to be:

```
1 
2 
3
```

But it's just printing carriage returns...  seems like it doesn't see the new values I added to the hash.

Thank you in advance

Below is my code which demonstrates my issue.

#### MAIN CODE

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use test_module;
our %hash;

$hash{a}="";
$hash{b}="";
$hash{c}="";

module::add_number();

my @letters = (sort keys %hash);
for my $letter (@letters) {
    print "$hash{$letter}{number}\n";
}
```

#### MODULE CODE

```
package test_module;

sub add_number {
    $hash{a}{number}=1;
    $hash{b}{number}=2;
    $hash{c}{number}=3;
}

1
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you're expecting. You're calling `module::add_number`, which doesn't exist -- there is only a `test_module::add_number`. And the `add_number` subroutine is modifying the `$%test_module::hash` hash whereas your main code is printing `%main::hash`

You must ***always*** `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every Perl program. That will reveal many simple errors that are easily overlooked

You should also avoid package variables unless they are unavoidable. Lexical variables -- declared with `my` -- should be your first choice. In addition, global identifiers such as package names should be capitalised, whereas lexical identifiers use just lower-case letters

Your main program sets `$hash{a}` etc. to null strings, after which the `add_number` subroutine requires them to be hash references so that it can set element `number` of the subsidiary hash. It is best not to initialise the hash elements if you need to do this

Finally, it is better to pass hash and array variables by reference if you need to modify them in separate subroutines, rather than declaring an `our` variable and fully-qualifying it with the package name to determine which one you're talking about

Your code should look like this

#### main.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use TestModule;

my %hash;

TestModule::add_number(\%hash);

my @letters = sort keys %hash;

for my $letter (@letters) {
    print "$hash{$letter}{number}\n";
}
```

#### TestModule.pm

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package TestModule;

sub add_number {
    my ($hash) = @_;

    $hash->{a}{number} = 1;
    $hash->{b}{number} = 2;
    $hash->{c}{number} = 3;
}

1;
```

#### output

```
1
2
3
```

You could also export `add_number` from `TestModule` by changing it to this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package TestModule;

use Export qw/ import /;
our @EXPORT = qw/ add_number /;

sub add_number {
    my ($hash) = @_;

    $hash->{a}{number} = 1;
    $hash->{b}{number} = 2;
    $hash->{c}{number} = 3;
}

1;
```

Then the `use TestModule` statement in the main code will import the `add_number` identifier, and you can call it with just `add_number(\%hash)`

Answer (score 4):

The `%hash` variable in your `"MAIN CODE"` section and the `%hash` variable in your `"MODULE CODE"` section are *not* the same variable. One of them is `%main::hash` and the other is `%test_module::hash`;

If you want a subroutine to be able to modify a variable, you need to pass a *reference* to that variable:

Main code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use test_module;
my %hash;

$hash{a}="";
$hash{b}="";
$hash{c}="";

# | - typo here, needs the 'test_' prefix
# v
test_module::add_number(\%hash); 
# the \ creates a reference to your %hash variable

my @letters = (sort keys %hash);
for my $letter (@letters) {
    print "$hash{$letter}->{number}\n";
}
```

Module code:

```
package test_module;

sub add_number {
    my ($hash_ref) = @_;

    # now that this is a reference, you need to dereference
    # accesses with the -> operator
    $hash_ref->{a} = { number => 1 };
    $hash_ref->{b} = { number => 2 };
    $hash_ref->{c} = { number => 3 };
}

1;
```

Comment: thanks very much hunter, this worked perfectly.  I need to dissect what you did.  they syntax is more involved than i thought it would be.  but it is what it is.  and it's great! thanks for catching my typo btw

Comment: I'm creating keys outside and inside a subroutine on the same hash.  However, after the subroutine, the values in the keys I created before the subroutine is called, are now interpreted as array references.